# How to get the BufferedWriter to write to a text file?

Tags: java, bufferedreader, filereader, filewriter, bufferedwriter

I'm trying to make an appointment book program in Java, however the BufferedWriter doesn't seem to be writing to the file.

This code is all inside of a `try { } catch (FileNotFoundException) { } catch (IOException) { }` block

```
FileWriter writer = new FileWriter("Appointments" + name + ".txt", true);
BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(writer);

if (open == 'o') {
    FileReader reader = new FileReader("Appointments" + name + ".txt");
    BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(reader);
    while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
        if (line.indexOf("one-time") == line.length() - 8) {
            OneTime o = fromStringOneTime(line);
            oneTimes.add(o);
        }
        if (line.indexOf("daily") == line.length() - 5) {
            Daily d = fromStringDaily(line);
            dailys.add(d);
        }
        if (line.indexOf("monthly") == line.length() - 7) {
            Monthly m = fromStringMonthly(line);
            monthlys.add(m);
        }
    }
}
```

The while loop is just initializing all of the values currently in the file into 3 different ArrayLists.

Then I have a block of code to create the new objects once you have selected that you want to add an appointment (variables `desc` and `date` have been previously defined):

```
System.out.print("Enter if this is a (o)ne-time, (d)aily, or (m)onthly appointment: ");
freq = scanner.next().charAt(0);
if (freq == 'o') {
    OneTime o = new OneTime(desc, date.getDate());
    oneTimes.add(o);
    totalCount++;
    bufferedWriter.write(o.toString());
    bufferedWriter.newLine();
    valid = true;
} else if (freq == 'd') {
    Daily o = new Daily(desc, date.getDate());
    dailys.add(o);
    totalCount++;
    bufferedWriter.write(o.toString());
    bufferedWriter.newLine();
    valid = true;
} else if (freq == 'm') {
    Monthly o = new Monthly(desc, date.getDate());
    monthlys.add(o);
    totalCount++;
    bufferedWriter.write(o.toString());
    bufferedWriter.newLine();
    valid = true;
}
```

At the end of the try block, I have the lines `reader.close()` and `writer.close()`. So why is it that when I check the file that it should be saving to, it still appears blank? This is my first time dealing with file saving, so I'm not sure why it isn't working the way it should be.

Edit: File will now only read if the option was chosen to open an existing file instead of creating a new one

Comment: You can't read from and write to a file at the same time in most operating systems.

Comment: So then would it work if I just closed the reader right after I finish using it? Because I only need to use it for the initialization, in the first block of code I put in my post.

Comment: Can you try writing to a file with different file name and rename it at end of the program

Comment: How would I do that using the reader/writer? Also, keep in mind that I need to be appending text to the file that was read, so just having two independent files is not an option.

Comment: 1) Can I have a peek at one of those classes (OneTime, Daily or Monthly)?  2) Are you using Notepad or an IDE (If IDE, which one?)

Comment: Here is a link to a pastebin with all of the classes (minus a tester class): http://pastebin.com/uDuuM1UF

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes., Most of the operating system will not allow to read and write the same file. So you can go with the workaround by writing to a file with some temporary file name and rename it to original at the end of the program

```
try {
   FileWriter writer = new FileWriter("Appointments" + name + "1.txt", true);
   FileReader reader = new FileReader("Appointments" + name + ".txt");
   BufferedReader bufferedReader= new BufferedReader(reader);
   BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(writer);
   .......
} catch () {
   ......
} finally {
   bufferedReader.close();
   bufferedWriter.flush();
   bufferedWriter.close();
}

// Rename the file and delete temp file
File srcFile = new File("Appointments" + name + "1.txt");
File targerFile = new File("Appointments" + name + ".txt");
srcFile.renameTo(targetFile);
srcFile.delete();
```

Comment: Tried it, the file still remains empty. The second file with the `1` appended was created, but I never saw anything stored into it.

Comment: Have you called flush() or close() for bufferedWriter ?

Comment: Yes, I called both of them.

Comment: Since complete source is not available so bit difficult to identify the problem. You can do one thing, ①just hardcode some value to  bufferedWriter.write() and try because now completely new file name and no dependency with your reader or any other logic. If it works then check your logic where your data is formed.

Comment: bufferedWriter is not closed in your source code. can you call bufferedWriter.close();

Comment: That worked. Apparently just calling writer.close() and reader.close() is not enough, you have to call the buffered version instead.

Comment: I told in my second comment to check whether bufferedWriter has been flushed or closed. You told it has been done. Okay great that you have solved the problem.